# How to automatically transfer Images to a Folder

Tags: python-3.x, macos, file, automation

I've been trying to test out my auto file transfer program, but I can't figure out a way to make it know if the file is a ".png/.jpg" So it can automatically transfer screenshots to a folder instead from the desktop.

I have been trying different methods to do this, but there is just no luck. Please help.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import json

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_modified(self, event):
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            src = folder_to_track + "/" + filename
            new_destination = folder_destination + "/" + filename
            os.rename(src, new_destination)


folder_to_track = '/Users/mattbecute/Desktop'
folder_destination = '/Users/mattbecute/Desktop/Screenshots'
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `glob` package to list only those files ending with a particular extension.

```
import glob
folder_to_track = '/Users/mattbecute/Desktop'
im_files=glob.glob(folder_to_track+"/*.png")
```